# Does Jenkins' scheduled build use default parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized multijob project in Jenkins and I started a scheduled build.

Question:

Does Jenkins' scheduled build use default parameters from my parameterized multijob project?

Thanks for participation!

Comment: Yes, best way would be to just configure a multi job and run it and display the values using echo :)

Comment: yes, it will take the default parameter

Comment: @yashbagarka thank you for answer!

Comment: @Nirmal thanks for help too!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jenkins schedule build will take the default parameters from parameterized multijob project.